# Once a channel has auth'd, is there a way to query for the top X countries by views?

Tags: youtube-api

All I can find is this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/sample-requests#channel_country_viewcounts

and doing it that way means we would have to query for every country in the world, then sort.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the top countries by channel in the Content Owner reports and Channel Reports. I have included the links below showing you how to get the reports.

**Channel Reports**

Docs (check "country" dimensions report):
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports#Reports

API Explorer (great tool for testing API calls without writing code):
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?ids=channel%253D%253DCHANNEL_ID&start-date=2010-03-01&end-date=2013-07-31&metrics=views%252CestimatedMinutesWatched%252CaverageViewDuration%252CaverageViewPercentage%252CsubscribersGained&dimensions=country&sort=-estimatedMinutesWatched&_h=3&

API Request:
GET
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DCHANNEL_ID&start-date=2010-03-01&end-date=2013-07-31&metrics=views%2CestimatedMinutesWatched%2CaverageViewDuration%2CaverageViewPercentage%2CsubscribersGained&dimensions=country&sort=-estimatedMinutesWatched&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

**Content Owner Reports**

Content Owner reports docs (check "country" dimensions report):
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/content_owner_reports#Reports

API Explorer link (great tool for testing API calls without writing code):
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?ids=contentOwner%253D%253DCMS_ID&start-date=2009-01-27&end-date=2013-08-08&metrics=views&dimensions=country&filters=channel%253D%253DCHANNEL_ID&sort=-views&_h=3&

This is what the HTTP Request:
GET
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=contentOwner%3D%3DCMS_ID&start-date=2009-01-27&end-date=2013-08-08&metrics=views&dimensions=country&filters=channel%3D%3DCHANNEL_ID&sort=-views&key={YOUR_API_KEY}